# How can I get rid of these NuGet Packages?

Tags: nuget, maui

I wanted to enable Azure Push Notifications and Firebase Cloud Messaging in my .NET MAUI app. I followed the steps outlined in this video, [Implement Push Notification In .NET MAUI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBbbctEvbOk&t=1307s), adding some Xamarin assemblies, but ran into some issues. Now I'm trying to remove these references, but they keep reappearing.

My assemblies are seen in this image:
[image: Xamarin packages]

They cannot be removed by Manage NuGet Packages, as they are "implicitly reference by an SDK". I have tried navigating to the <user>\.nuget\packages folder by right-clicking from solution explorer, closing Visual Studio, deleting the folders, and then reopening Visual Studio.

The packages keep reappearing under the Dependencies>net7.0-android>Packages in Solution Explorer and are repopulated in the aforementioned folder in my <users> folder. How do I permanently get rid of them?

Comment: Your project's `.csproj` file is the ultimate "truth" of what gets included. There must be something in it, that depends on those. Make a new Maui solution and project. Compare its `.csproj` to the one that you are trying to clean up. Worst case, you can always start copying source files over to this new project, until you can figure out the difference. **Do you use git or other source code control?** Go back to a version before you made that change, look at its .csproj. (git can be used locally to preserve source versions; don't even need github or other server.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, Using git, I was able to see all of the changes in this csproj and the projects it depends on. What you stated makes sense, but I still am getting the same behavior after deleting the folders in .nuget/packages.

Comment: When you "added some Xamarin assemblies", are those Nuget packages? In .csproj, look for `<PackageReference >` lines. Remove any that are not listed in your old project version in git. (OR you could remove ALL PackageReferences, then see what build errors you get, add back as needed.)

Comment: They were packages, which I removed in the XML. They are gone now, that I have pursued another issue. I followed your directions, and they disappeared on their own time apparently. I did try turning it off and then back on again at one point :) Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

According to ToolmakerSteve, in `.csproj`, delete `<PackageReference >` lines that represent the packages you want to get rid of.

For more info you can refer to this doc: [`PackageReference` in project files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files).